# AD Trusts and browsing the Entire Windows Network

Tags: networking, active-directory

I've recently setup a Trust between 3 AD servers and I'm being asked if we should be able to browse the entire Windows network and see the other AD servers and resources. I was under the impression that a Trust is a way for resources to be shared and not necessarily to allow users to browse the network and see servers.

Can someone elaborate on this for me so I get my facts straight? Is this indeed something that we should be able to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An active directory trust is there to provide authentication and authorization for resource access between domains and/or forests, that's it. Whether or not your able to browse to networks resources is a function of your network infrastructure, not AD. Once you have located the resources, AD takes care of whether or not you have the rights to access them.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks, Sam. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not going to work without a lot of setup. You would need to set up a central WINS server, configure the clients and servers in each of the three domains to register with the central WINS server, allow WINS traffic through the firewalls, allow network browsing traffic through the firewalls, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. And for the answer on that other site too :)

Comment: Happy to help. Hope you get it worked out.